# jQuery hover tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create simple jQuery tabs. The tab content should be displayed on hover. So I'm trying following code. The problem is that if you hover fast enough on the tab titles, you can still see the other tabs content before the right tab content is displayed.

**Demo:**

Please see the Fiddle link to see the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/0v9nhxu3/

**Code:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".tab-titles li").hover(function() {
        $(".tab-content").hide();
        $(".tab-titles li").removeClass('active');                  
        $(this).addClass("active");                 
        var selected_tab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        $(selected_tab).fadeIn();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: why downvote? please enlighten me whats wrong with the question?

Comment: I agree this question is fine +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) before `fadeIn` to stop the current running animation.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".tab-titles li").hover(function() {
        $(".tab-content").hide();
        $(".tab-titles li").removeClass('active');                  
        $(this).addClass("active");                 
        var selected_tab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        $(selected_tab).stop().fadeIn();
        return false;
    });
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0v9nhxu3/1/)

Comment: As a side note, using `hover()` method in/out handler seems inappropriate here

Comment: @A.Wolff What would be better solution? Thanks.

Comment: @user1355300 Just replace `hover` with `mouseover` e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/0v9nhxu3/10/

Comment: @user1355300 Replace **hover** ---> **mouseover** and **$(selected_tab).fadeIn();**---> **$(selected_tab).fadeIn(.5);**

Answer (score 1):

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".tab-titles li").hover(function() {
            $(".tab-content").removeClass('tab-show');
            $(".tab-titles li").removeClass('active');                  
            $(this).addClass("active");                 
            var selected_tab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
            $(selected_tab).addClass("tab-show");
            return false;
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0v9nhxu3/9/

Answer (score 1):

Quick way and customizable

```js
$(function(){
   $('.tabs li').hover(function(){
     //hover in
       var index= $(this).index();
       $('.tabcontainer div').eq(index).show(500);
   },function(){
     //hover out
       $('.tabcontainer div').hide(500);
   });
})
```

```css
.tabcontainer{
    padding: 20px;
 }
.tabcontainer div{
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border: thin solid #ccc;
}
.tabs{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.tabs li{
   list-style: none;
   padding: 10px;
   display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tabs li:hover{
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabcontainer">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li>Tab 1</li>
        <li>Tab 2</li>
        <li>Tab 3</li>
        <li>Tab 4</li>      
    </ul>
    <div>Tab 1 content</div>
    <div>Tab 2 content</div>
    <div>Tab 3 content</div>
    <div>Tab 4 content</div>  
</div>
```